# Adding index in table suggestion?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table called Products with `ID(PK, Clustered), Name, Price, Brand, ...., RetailerID, SKU, ModelNumber`. My query have

```
SELECT .... 
FROM Products 
WHERE RetailerID = @RetailerID AND 
      ( (@SKU != '' AND SKU = @SKU)  OR (@ModelNumber != '' AND ModelNumber = @ModelNumber))
```

I am going to add index for this query. Should I add 3 indices on RetailerID , SKU and ModelNumber or 2 compound indices on (RetailerID, SKU) and (RetailerID, ModelNumber) or 1 compund index on (RetailerID, ModelNumber, SKU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a seperate index on SKU and ModelNumber. I don't think an index on RetailerID will do much good as there won't be many different retailers .

The best approach to analyze this is by comparing the execution plans & times of the different sets of indexes

Comment: You don't want to rewrite this in a union :) . Here's some more info about the union syntax: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx